# ./python: symbol lookup error: ./python: undefined symbol: __gcov_indirect_call_profiler when compiling python

Tags: python-3.x

I am compiling python with the following options...

```
./configure --prefix="$PREFIX" --enable-optimizations --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=$PREFIX/lib"
```

and got the following error:

```
./python: undefined symbol: __gcov_indirect_call_profiler
```

It compiled fine the first time, but when I started changing options and recompiling later, I got this error.  Changing the options back to the original options didn't help.

What is causing this?

Comment: I realize that this is a self-answered question, but I recommend perhaps elaborating on "sometimes" to let others in the future find this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is also mentioned here, https://bugs.python.org/issue29712

What is happening is that if you've already done a compilation and installed into `$PREFIX`, then during a second compile, a step in the makefile will dynamically load the `.so` library from `$PRFEFIX/lib` rather than the build environment.

If you `rm -rf $PREFIX` prior to compiling, you should get a clean build.

I think this has to do with the profile based optimization step of the build and the installed library is missing some expected symbols for that.